# Can't get Visual Studio _references.js to update

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, unit-testing, jasmine

There's a lot of mention about the creation of a `_references.js` file and getting it to auto-update when you have a number of JavaScript scripts to reference.

But in my unit test project (for Jasmine) I can not get the two menu options to appear.  I've tried various folders and locations, removing addin's etc

Comment: what's wrong or not clear in the question? so that I can update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Visual Studio only has the `_references` menu options if your project is already a Web Project.  I'd created a standard Unit Test project, and this was the root cause.

So if your creating a separate Jasmine (or other JavaScript) test project in Visual Studio create an Empty Web project.

I don't know if the Web Performance test project works or not, as I've never used it.